# iphone can't post to my rails app

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, objective-c, ios

So I have been trying out several different ways to connect my iPhone app to my ROR restful backend and all seems to work ok pulling down data (json) with 'get' requests, but when posting I am unable to do so.  I have tried ObjectiveResource and two or three others and they all have the same issue. I am thinking its something set wrong in my ROR app?  I did notice all the example iPhone projects use https for production apps, does a production app need to https for an iPhone to establish a session and be able to post?

HERE is what I get for an error if I use http://localhost:3000/posts

Processing PostsController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-05 20:49:42) [POST]
  Parameters: {"post"=>{"budget"=>"222"}}
User interests hash: false

NoMethodError (undefined method `posts' for false:FalseClass):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:113:in`create'

If I use http://localhost:3000

Processing PostsController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-05 20:49:42) [POST]
  Parameters: {"post"=>{"budget"=>"222"}}

Here is my Create method:
  def create
    #@post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfully created.'
    format.html { redirect_to(@post) }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post } 
    format.json { render :json => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post } 
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity } 
    format.json { render :json => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Here is the method:

```
# POST /posts
# POST /posts.xml
 def create
#@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfully created.'
    format.html { redirect_to(@post) }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post } 
    format.json { render :json => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post } 
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity } 
    format.json { render :json => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Iphone call:

```
 // CRUD methods using Resource.h 
- (void)createRemote {
NSString *url =
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/posts", siteURL];
[Resource post:[self params] to:url];
}
```

%@/posts is equal to http://localhost:3000/posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `protect_from_forgery` set on your ApplicationController?

This essentially kills POSTing information from anywhere except the forms on your website.  Try commenting it out and see if things start working.

Answer (score 1):

As peterjb said, check for forgery protection. If you're on rails 3 then look for the `csrf_meta_tag` in your application.html.erb.

Answer (score 0):

https  -- is not must, it is how your server configures for the security needs. You can have http and https both no issues.

I suggest you to have look at the log in ROR app end too know what you get HTTP POST data -- if you are not able to get any data in ROR app end post some code which does POST request from your iPhone, people can analyse it better.

Comment: Here is what I get Processing PostsController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-05 20:38:25) [POST]
  Parameters: {"post"=>{"budget"=>"12121"}}
User interests hash: false

NoMethodError (undefined method `posts' for false:FalseClass):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:113:in `create'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'

Comment: See original post for chanes.